# Does the sequence of the $n$th Brillouin zones converges to any particular geometrical form?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

I am currently studying solid state physics and we just saw the construction of the  Brillouin zones. My question is the following:

Does the sequence of the $n$th Brillouin zones converges to any particular geometrical form? From some figures I have seen, it seems to tend to a circle ( for different lattices ) but if this is true, I don't have any idea why and whether it is convergent whatever the form of the lattice at the beginning.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: This is an interesting geometry question, but I guess the point is that a high enough order polygon is bound to look like a circle, especially with the symmetries of Brillouin zones enforced.

Comment: @KFGauss - I agree, with the caveat that you start with a high symmetry crystal. Books rarely have nice pictures of the Brillouin zones or Fermi surface of a triclinic crystal...

Answer (score 1):

This was studied by mathematician Gareth A. Jones in the paper [*Geometric and Asymptotic Properties of Brillouin Zones in Lattices*](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/16.3.241), Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society **16**, 241 (1984). Non-paywalled link [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.850.4433&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

The relevant conclusion is that, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, the $n$-th Brillouin zone approaches the shape of a thin spherical shell of radius $O(n^{1/d})$, where $d=1,2,3,\dots$ is the dimension of the lattice. This fact implies that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}B_n$ approaches the shape of the $d-1$-sphere $S^{d-1}$. I.e. in two dimensions you get a circle $S^1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and in three dimensions you get the regular sphere.

---

A possibly relevant follow-up paper is Jones. and Lansberg [*Brillouin Zones and the Fundamental Regions*](https://doi.org/10.1002/pssb.2221280228), Physica Status Solidi b **128**, 619 (1985). I have not read it, but from its abstract it appears to describe some properties of the $n$-th Brillouin zone.